# Joining Tables where 1 value doesn't have to be the same

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I need to join the two tables below in SQL Server 2014, I used the following code but my problem is where Sales_org does not match. If it doesn't match it should return a value based on just Material and not Sales Organisation.
Reason why it's 0 is that it's the same for both countries.

```
Left Join 
[Z_PACKING] on [CTE_OPMAO2].[Material] = [Z_PACKING].[Material number]
AND
[CTE_OPMAO2].[Sales_org] = [Z_PACKING].[Sales Organization]
```

I tried using "OR" but got stuck.

**[CTE_OPMAO2]**
 ==============

```
Sales_org |   Material                           

2110      |    005013K                 
2190      |    036060J                 
2190      |    036280J                 
2190      |    036353J
2110      |    037380K
2110      |    037740K
```

**[Z_Packing]**
 ==============

```
Sales_org |    Material number   |    Packaging                    

2110      |    005013K           |       PC      
2190      |    036060J           |       PAC    
2190      |    036280J           |       CAR   
0         |    036353J           |       PC
0         |    037380K           |       PC
0         |    037740K           |       PC
```

Comment: please provide the whole select query

Comment: Select * from CTE_OPMAO2 Left Join [Z_PACKING] on [CTE_OPMAO2].[Material] = [Z_PACKING].[Material number] AND [CTE_OPMAO2].[Sales_org] = [Z_PACKING].[Sales Organization]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you got stock, forgot the ()?

```
select *
from CTE_OPMAO2
Left Join [Z_PACKING] on [CTE_OPMAO2].[Material] = [Z_PACKING].[Material number] 
AND ([CTE_OPMAO2].[Sales_org] = [Z_PACKING].[Sales Organization] 
     or [Z_PACKING].[Sales Organization] = 0)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the info, I tried that and it worked, but I went from 72154 records to 72305 which doesn't make sense to me considering a left join should keep the original rows intact.

Comment: Left join won't have less records than in left table, but can have more. In Zpacking you may have duplicate materials. You can add a constraint on your table to prevent that happening.

Comment: Thanks, apparently there were duplicates that shouldn't have been in there, issue resolved!

Comment: @AbdelB. Glad I could help you. If you think this answer helped you, then you can click the V Left of the answer, to mark it as best answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, not used to using stackoverflow to ask question, always been a lurker. ;)